# Updater process ended with ERROR: 1 [TWRP]

Tags: custom-roms, twrp, redmi

I was using Pixel experience 10.0 on Redmi 5A (Riva) and I decided to clean install Pixel experience 11.0 today. But I'm getting the following error on TWRP.

```
Installing zip file '/sdcard/Pixel Experience Riva 11.0.zip'
Checking for Digest file...
assert failed: riva.verify_trustzone("TZ.BF.4.0.5-157266") == "1"
Updater process ended with ERROR: 1
Error installing zip file '/sdcard/Pixel Experience Riva 11.0.zip'
Updating partition details...
...done
```

**Note that:**

- I formatted the device with TWRP and wiped System, Dalvik, Data, Cache partitions.
- I was using Pixel Experience before and my Bootloader is unlocked.
- Previous version of the ROM (Pixel experience 10.0) is installing successfully.
- My TWRP version is 3.4.0-0, and latest version of TWRP (3.5.0_9-0) doesn't support on the device.

Comment: wrong tz partition (and probably more)

Comment: How to fix it? Is it a problem of ROM?

Comment: yes, underlaying stock ROM version mismatch. read the installation instructions

Comment: [I did that already](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/riva/install/), but I think I had 7.1.1 way before. Do I have to install the stock ROM again?

Comment: restore backup or install previous pixel version. or edit updater-script in zip file (remove the assert line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by installing [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xiaomi-firmware-updater/files/Stable/V10/riva/fw_riva_miui_HM5AGlobal_V10.1.1.0.NCKMIFI_8cb19207b7_7.1.zip/download) zip. Then I installed the ROM.

[Official guide link](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/riva/install/)

Thanks [@alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470/alecxs)